# copy multiple pdf files data to excel in different worksheets

Tags: c, vba, excel, pdf

I have created a vba script to copy all data from multiple pdf files and paste in a excel in different tabs with the same name of the pdf files.

Problem is its copying data from pdf files and pasting in the same tab of the worksheet replacing one over another. Please let me where i am going wrong with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reset `wsOutp` before checking if it is nothing. 
As written, you are setting `wsOutp` to reference a sheet on your initial loop.  You then must reset it to nothing before the next loop, because when you try to set it to reference another sheet which may not exist, if that fails the reference still points to the original sheet.  So what ends up happening, is you delete the sheet on the next step.

So in reality your code is not overwriting to the *same* sheet, but you are deleting each sheet you create, so in the end you are left with only one sheet.

Add the line below:

```
    ' Delete sheet with filename if exists
    Set wsOutp = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsOutp = Sheets(strFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not wsOutp Is Nothing Then
        wsOutp.Delete
    End If
```